# What is the range of the disturbance that the pulse causes on the rope?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I'm learning the basics of waves via [this post](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Introductory_Physics_-_Building_Models_to_Describe_Our_World_(Martin_Neary_Rinaldo_and_Woodman)/14%3A_Waves/14.03%3A_Waves_on_a_Rope), which gives this figure to modeling the propagation of a wave.

[image]

> We can model the propagation speed of the pulse by considering the speed, , of point  that is shown in the left panel …

Is the point  at where pointed out by red or blue arrow in the right panel?

In other words, what is the range of the disturbance that the pulse causes on the rope?

Are the parts pointed out by the red ellipses are the disturbance represent the disturbance that the pulse causes on the rope?

[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/211204/59023 ?

Comment: Have a look at this PhET simulation, [Waves on a string](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/wave-on-a-string/latest/wave-on-a-string_en.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use to demonstrate pulses on a long narrow spring stretched across the front of a classroom.  The shape and duration of a pulse was determined by the motion of my hand. The pulse would propagate to the far wall, reflect, and come back. The range of a pulse in a rope will depend on dissipative forces within the rope and friction with its surroundings.